# Programmatically adding "Open Recent' menu to context popup menu

Tags: cocoa, contextmenu, menubar

I have a non-document Cocoa application with a menubar icon and status menu. I've added an "Open Recent" menu to the status menu in Interface Builder. Populating the menu works just fine:

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] noteNewRecentDocumentURL:
            [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filename]]
```

Now I would also like to **add a second** "Open Recent" menu to a context popup menu. How would I create the menu programmatically so that it gets populated with entries automatically as it does for the version in the status menu?

I tried creating a copy of the one in the status menu, but it does not get populated. I assume that NSDocumentController is not aware of the menu (frankly, I don't know how it knows about the one in the status menu).

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the best documentation on the inner workings of the *Open Recent* menu that I found is this:
http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/07/10/working-without-a-nib-part-5-open-recent-menu/

Unfortunately, it doesn’t help much with this, because even if you create the menu like this, it will be ignored by `NSDocumentController`. The menu must exist in the main menu before `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` call, otherwise it won’t be picked up — and consequently, duplicate ones are ignored too.

What I ended up doing, and what seems to work so far, is this:

The first idea was to pick the corresponding `NSMenu` from the main menu and attach it into other menus as well, hoping that reference counting will make this work. No such luck, `setSubmenu` throws if the submenu is already in another `NSMenuItem`.

So I “reparent” the submenu instead — when I need to show it in another menu, I remove it from the main menu’s *Open Recent* item and set it as submenu in the new menu. Later, I move it back. It’s an ugly hack, of course, but it gets the job done.